# Saving state of WebView and restoring in ANDROID

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I have an Android application which built with `ViewPager` and seperated WebView's in each page. Every `WebView` points different web sites. For instance, Page1: facebook, Page2: Twitter, Page3: Google+. User can add/remove pages.

My `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` (where `mPager` is an instance of `ViewPager`). Which means, when user views 3. page, the first fragment is being disposed (and re-created when user views 2. page again).

What I want is to save first WebView's state before destroys and save its state somewhere, and then restore it when user sees it. Because it reloads the page and obviously its annoying. And I don't want user to reload web pages on every swipe. I have tried with

```
mWebView.saveState(outState);
mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
```

but it doesn't seem work. Any ideas for saving and restoring states of webviews?

I have tried saving WebView itself in some class, saving states etc.

Comment: have you got any solution for this problem.

Comment: Nope, I have just set mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3), where 3 is total pages of my mPager. But it's not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `setOffscreenPageLimit()` sets the number of pages to keep to either the left or the right of current page.

From `FragmentPagerAdapter` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html):

> The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory,
>   though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This
>   can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment
>   instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state.

I think in your case since WebViews can be quite large in memory, Android disposes of it until it is needed again.